# Trying to protect my Sqlite3 DB with password in C

Tags: c, sqlite, password-protection

I followed the instructions in https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt and still, I can open my DB without any password,

this is the sequence I'm using:

```
sqlite3_open("DATA", &db);
sqlite3_user_authenticate(db, "root", "1234", strlen("1234"));
sqlite3_user_add(db, "root", "1234", strlen("1234"), 1);
```

I can see that I have the 'sqlite_user' table(after sqlite3_user_add() called) with my username and BLOB password and the 'isAdmin' field =1.

uname = root

isAdmin = 1

pw = y▒▒%▒▒lH▒Ե

I'm executing my queries in Linux using shell commands, for example:
sqlite3 -line DATA.DB  "select * from products"

Comment: Not sure, but do you close the database when done? Maybe a session remains open.

Comment: yes, of course, the DB is closed at the end of every session

Comment: If your version of the sqlite3 shell wasn't built with support for this extension, it'll open database files like normal. (And if it was, there's no way to provide a user name or password...)